# The effect of inserting a nonnegative diagonal matrix between A and A transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a full row rank matrix. It is known for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $x^{\top}AA^{\top}x \geq \lambda_{\min}(AA^{\top})\|x\|^2$. Let $0 \neq d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $D=\text{diag}(d)$ be the diagonal matrix associated with $d$.

Is there a $c>0$ such that:
$$
x^{\top}ADDA^{\top}x \geq c\lambda_{\min}(AA^{\top})\|d\|^2\|x\|^2.
$$

Or, is there a $c>$ only a function of $A$, i.e., $c(A)$ such that:

$$
x^{\top}ADDA^{\top}x \geq c(A)\|d\|^2\|x\|^2.
$$

**My try:**

I can write $ADDA^{\top}=\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2A_{i}(A_i)^{\top}$ where $A_i$ is the $i$-th column of $A$. I do not know how I can go furthure?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Can you please let me know which part of my writing needs $m=n$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: My bad. I edited my statement, i.e., $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Answer (score 1):

Unless $m=n=1$, no such strictly positive function $c$ exists.

Suppose $m>1$. If the inequality holds, it must hold in particular, or by a continuity argument, when $D$ is rank-one. Yet, when $m>1$ and $D$ is rank-one, $DA^T$ has a non-trivial kernel. Therefore the LHS of the inequality is zero for some nonzero vector $x$, but the RHS, unless $c\le 0$, is strictly positive.

When $m=1$, $A$ is a nonzero row vector and $x$ is a scalar (or strictly speaking, a $1\times1$ matrix). Let us write it as $y^T$ instead. The inequality can then be rewritten as
$$
\|Dy\|^2\ge c(y^T)\|d\|^2,
$$
which is true if we take $c(y^T)=\min_i y_i^2$. However, this $c$ is strictly positive only when $n$ is also equal to $1$, otherwise it is merely weakly positive.

Comment: What if rank of $D$ is $r$?

Comment: @Sepide If $c$ is a continuous function and the inequality is true for $D$ of rank $r\ge1$, it must also be true for $D$ of rank one, because every rank-one diagonal matrix is the limit of some sequence of rank-$r$ diagonal matrices.